# pySpark: is it possible to groupBy() with one single node per group?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pySpark to compute per-group matrices. It looks like the computation would be faster if Spark stored any given group's rows on one single node, so Spark could compute each matrix locally. I'm afraid inter-node cooperation could take much longer.

Do `map()` and `groupBy()` usually achieve this kind of thing? Should I try to specify it as an option, if possible?

NB. The matrices include computing a distance between each row and the previous one, within each (sorted) group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Spark will do that by default.

See here : http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-groupby-example/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you asked for `mapPartitions()`. Then the operation happens locally in each partition.